# Generating the same SHA1 UUID in golang and Javascript

Tags: javascript, go, cryptography, sha

I have what I thought was a pretty simply question. I'm using this code to generate a SHA1 uuid in Golang:

```
namespace := uuid.Parse("b9cfdb9d-f741-4e1f-89ae-fac6b2a5d740")
sha := uuid.NewSHA1(namespace, []byte("something"))
fmt.Println(sha.String())
```

Now I want to generate the same UUID in javascript, and I thought it would be as easy as something like this:

```
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA1("b9cfdb9d-f741-4e1f-89ae-fac6b2a5d740" + "something")
// chomp the hash into a UUID string
```

However, I'm running into serious issues. It seems that the `uuid.Parse` function in Golang is running [this parsing function](https://code.google.com/p/go-uuid/source/browse/uuid/util.go#39) that converts the namespace to a 16-byte array, so even though I use the same SHA1 algorithm in Javascript, I'm not getting the same output.

I'v been messing around with doing the same in JS, but I'm stumped.

Any smart crypto people in here that can help me?

Comment: Sorry, just added a snippet.

Comment: Can you show both results?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I looked into the meaning of "parsing" an UUID. It seems that it will remove the dashes, convert the values and produce a byte array. Ronze I think you could try removing the hashes, perform hex decode and then SHA1, but I'm not sure.

Comment: [Now I am sure](https://code.google.com/p/go-uuid/source/browse/uuid/uuid.go?r=4f1c1d3e2957d4fad2fe354912bebb69cf5928e6)

Comment: ...but there are more calculations in `NewSHA1`, that's not just SHA1. OK, enough reasons to at least vote up.

Comment: Thanks maarten. I still can't figure out how to do this. I understand that I need to turn the SHA1 into a UUID, but the Golang code can help me with that. It's just grabbing the first `n` characters and adding the `-`. But I can't seem to generate the same SHA1 no matter what I do with the namespace.

Comment: do you want SHA1 or NewSHA1? Apparently they are different implementation with NewSHA1 adding another hash bit in the mix as in version 5?

Comment: The part I'm not certain you're getting is that, for the javascript, you must hex decode the namespace string before you hash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, that only took me a month.

```
var SHA1Generator = {

    hex_chr: "0123456789abcdef",

    hex: function (num) {
        var str = "";
        for (var j = 7; j >= 0; j--)
            str += this.hex_chr.charAt((num >> (j * 4)) & 0x0F);
        return str;
    },


    str2blks_SHA1: function (str) {
        var nblk = ((str.length + 8) >> 6) + 1;
        var blks = new Array(nblk * 16);
        for (var i = 0; i < nblk * 16; i++) blks[i] = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
            blks[i >> 2] |= str.charCodeAt(i) << (24 - (i % 4) * 8);
        blks[i >> 2] |= 0x80 << (24 - (i % 4) * 8);
        blks[nblk * 16 - 1] = str.length * 8;
        return blks;
    },


    add: function (x, y) {
        var lsw = (x & 0xFFFF) + (y & 0xFFFF);
        var msw = (x >> 16) + (y >> 16) + (lsw >> 16);
        return (msw << 16) | (lsw & 0xFFFF);
    },


    rol: function (num, cnt) {
        return (num << cnt) | (num >>> (32 - cnt));
    },


    ft: function (t, b, c, d) {
        if (t < 20) return (b & c) | ((~b) & d);
        if (t < 40) return b ^ c ^ d;
        if (t < 60) return (b & c) | (b & d) | (c & d);
        return b ^ c ^ d;
    },


    kt: function (t) {
        return (t < 20) ? 1518500249 : (t < 40) ? 1859775393 :
         (t < 60) ? -1894007588 : -899497514;
    },

    calcSHA1FromByte: function(byteArr) {
        var str = '';
        for(var i=0; i<byteArr.length; i++)
            str += String.fromCharCode(byteArr[i]);
        return this.calcSHA1(str);
    },

    calcSHA1: function (str) {
        if (str != '') {
            var x = this.str2blks_SHA1(str);
            var w = new Array(80);

            var a = 1732584193;
            var b = -271733879;
            var c = -1732584194;
            var d = 271733878;
            var e = -1009589776;

            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i += 16) {
                var olda = a;
                var oldb = b;
                var oldc = c;
                var oldd = d;
                var olde = e;

                for (var j = 0; j < 80; j++) {
                    if (j < 16) w[j] = x[i + j];
                    else w[j] = this.rol(w[j - 3] ^ w[j - 8] ^ w[j - 14] ^ w[j - 16], 1);
                    t = this.add(this.add(this.rol(a, 5), this.ft(j, b, c, d)), this.add(this.add(e, w[j]), this.kt(j)));
                    e = d;
                    d = c;
                    c = this.rol(b, 30);
                    b = a;
                    a = t;
                }

                a = this.add(a, olda);
                b = this.add(b, oldb);
                c = this.add(c, oldc);
                d = this.add(d, oldd);
                e = this.add(e, olde);
            }
            return this.hex(a) + this.hex(b) + this.hex(c) + this.hex(d) + this.hex(e);
        }
        else {
            return '';
        }
    }
};

function stringToByteArray(str) {
  var bytes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
      bytes.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
  }
  return bytes;
}

function uuidToByteArray(hex) {

  // If this is a uuid, remove the dashes
  hex = hex.replace(/-/g, "");

  // convert each hex number into a string representation
  // of the byte integer.
  var bytes = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2) {
    bytes.push(parseInt(hex.substring(i, i+2),16));
  }

  return bytes;
}

function sha1ToUUID5(hash) {
  var uuid =  hash.substring(0, 8) +
    '-' + hash.substring(8, 12) +
    // four most significant bits holds version number 5
    '-' + ((parseInt(hash.substring(12, 16), 16) & 0x0fff) | 0x5000).toString(16) +
    // two most significant bits holds zero and one for variant DCE1.1
    '-' + ((parseInt(hash.substring(16, 20), 16) & 0x3fff) | 0x8000).toString(16) +
    '-' + hash.substring(20, 32); //12 digits
  return uuid;
}

var namespace = "e75a36a9-3323-40dd-a7d1-1c57ad2aa3cd"
var id = "event154"

var namespaceBytes = uuidToByteArray(namespace);
var idBytes = stringToByteArray(id);
var allBytes = namespaceBytes.concat(idBytes);

console.log("ORG 4505612c-c323-5d6f-b5cc-b7f362b9ba55")
console.log("NEW " + sha1ToUUID5(SHA1Generator.calcSHA1FromByte(allBytes)))
```

Comment: How would this look like using a lib like node-forge which has SHA and hex tooling on board?